# SMTP - Fast and reliable connection probing without auth?

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

## Briefing

I am currently building a python *SMTP Mail sender program*.

I added a feature so that the user **would not be able to log in if there was no active internet connection**, I tried many solutions/variations to make the real time connection checking as swift as possible, there were many problems such as:

1. The thread where the connection handler was running suddenly lagged when I pulled out the ethernet cable ( to test how it would handle the sudden disconnect )
2. The whole program crashed
3. It took several seconds for the program to detect the change

### My current solution

**I set up a data handling class** which would contain all the necessary info ( the modules needed to share info effectively )

```
import smtplib
from socket import gaierror, timeout

class DataHandler:
    is_logged_in = None
    is_connected = None
    server_conn = None
    user_address = ''
    user_passwd = ''

    @staticmethod
    def try_connect():
        try:
            DataHandler.server_conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587, timeout=1) # The place where the connection is checked
            DataHandler.is_connected = True
        except (smtplib.SMTPException, gaierror, timeout):
            DataHandler.is_connected = False # Connection status changed upon a connection error
```

**I put a connection handler class on a second thread**, the server connection process slowed down the gui when it was all on one thread.

```
from root_gui import Root
import threading
from time import sleep
from data_handler import DataHandler


def handle_conn():
    DataHandler.try_connect()
    smtp_client.refresh() # Refreshes the gui according to the current status


def conn_manager(): # Working pretty well
    while 'smtp_client' in globals():
        sleep(0.6) 
        try:
            handle_conn() # Calls the connection
        except NameError: # If the user quits the tkinter gui
            break


smtp_client = Root()
handle_conn()


MyConnManager = threading.Thread(target=conn_manager)
MyConnManager.start()
smtp_client.mainloop()
del smtp_client # The connection manager will detect this and stop running
```

## My question is:

**Is this a good practice or a terrible waste of resources? Is there a better way to do this because no matter what I tried, this was the only solution that worked.**

From what I know the *try_connect()* function creates a completely new smtp object each time it is run ( **which is once in 0.6 seconds!** )

### Resources/observations

The project on git: https://github.com/cernyd/smtp_client

Observation: the *timeout* parameter when creating the smtp object improved response times drastically, why is that so?